# Eclipse PDT - How to use for Java development

Tags: java, php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I use PDT for PHP development. I am going to start learning Java. What packages should I install in PDT in order to have at least the same functionality as if I would fresh install [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosr)?

Comment: It would probably easiest to get the standard eclipse download for java developers, and have two eclipse installations (they can merrily coexist :-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to install JDT plugin with current eclipse installation.

http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/

Depending upon your eclipse version add following remote site  (from help>install new software>add ) and check for Java plugins:

Galileo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

Comment: It is better to install the full EPP package for Java. See this post for Galileo, it's about the same for Helios: http://bewarethepenguin.blogspot.com/2009/07/screencast-creating-eclipse-download.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use basic Java functionality, just select Window->Open Perspective->(Others...->)Java and you are good to go. As Eclipse is written in Java, the basic functions are always included. Even the debugger should be available.

I use my Eclipse with Aptana also for Java development.